# Best websites for correspondence chess?

Tags: websites, correspondence-chess

I've had some bad experiences with Chess.com recently. What are some good alternative websites for correspondence chess? I'm particularly looking for:

1. No time limit
2. Email notifications when it is your turn
3. Ideally, you should be able to make moves by replying to notification emails (with a simple expression like e2e4)

Thoughts?

Comment: It would help if you shared those bad experiences. They could be something unique to chess.com, or something that you could expect with any online chess site.

Comment: See #1-3 above.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't generally work well for questions that are just polling the community. The guidance is "real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions." For some more information, there's a good blog post titled [Real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: Maybe reword the question as to what websites are available.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from chess.com, here are a few others:

- http://www.queenalice.com
- http://www.gameknot.com
- http://www.redhotpawn.com
- http://www.chessos.com
- http://www.chess-mail.com

There are many out there...

Comment: Thanks for this list. Do you have a personal preference? In your experience, do any of these meet the specific criteria mentioned in the question (particularly #3)?

Comment: All are good, just pick one with a lot of people so you will always get a game. I did use gameknot for awhile because it has a good community but the admin support was non existent.

Comment: Most would be able to send e-mail notifications. I don't think any would do #1 or #3.

Comment: [lichess](https://lichess.org/) offers correspondance chess with a time limit of max 14 days. Hope this helps!