# How do I find people to play chess with me through correspondence?

Tags: learning, engines, online-chess, notation, correspondence-chess

I really would like to play chess, nevertheless, I do not have access to physical chess players. My question is, how do I find people to play chess with me by email? I have not been successful in finding anyone yet. I would like to play against a human, as I would like to practice AN, and that I think that a human is more interesting to play against. The computer is rather boring...
   Also, I would be interested in playing Chess Variants, such as Hex Chess. People who play such seem to be even more rare.
   In conclusion, I need help on how to find someone to play against, not only chess, but chess variants. As for the variants, I would be happy to know how to access them online or download them, as well.
   Thank you! I look forward to learning these things.

Comment: chesss.com you can play normal chess960, you can play a move per 14 days max

Answer (score 3):

I have never been particularly interested in correspondence chess, but the internet is full of chess servers. On many of them can you play correspondence chess:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_chess_servers

Here is a similar question, with a possibly useful answer:

[Best websites for correspondence chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/best-websites-for-correspondence-chess)

Answer (score 2):

The USCF can help you, if you're in the USA.

[click here](http://www.uschess.org/content/blogcategory/82/393/)

Answer (score 2):

Chess. com has correspondence chess with move time limits. Its a good option though if you want more letters written back and forth it isnt for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [OTB Chess](https://otbchess.org) Community. It was created for exactly this user case.

There you can find your city and see if anyone is interested in playing, or you can offer someone to play. If you city doesn't exist yet, then it will get created very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [It's Your Turn](http://www.itsyourturn.com/).

There you can play correspondence chess, as well as many different chess-variants (including Hex) and other games (like Go, for example). Basic usage is free, upgrading your account offers more options, but it is not free. I have been playing correspondence chess on this site for some years now, without upgrading my account and I am pretty happy with the site. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

redhotpawn.com,

You can play for free or access tournaments thru a subscription (50 USD p/yr).

Has the usual facilities (keep an archive of all your games, get notification by email when an opponent has played, etc).

I used to play a lot myself, but lastly don't have a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

ICCF  hosts postal play and has various competitions including THE world championship for postal.  Check out https://www.iccf.com/

The USCF also hosts the old CL&R postal games now that they have taken  over that old magazine via a merger with CL.  Check out http://www.uschess.org/content/blogcategory/82/393/

I suspect that their postal play is via the internet with longer clock time than OTB not the old fashioned snail mail that added many days or weeks to the allowed time.   You had to answer in 3 days of receipt back then but could think during the mails transit to gain more clock time in effect.